# iPad OS 13 beta UIWebView crash on switch input

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, ipados, ipados13

On UIWebView; In input type text when I enter the key '@@@@' (on Japanese keyboard) and then switch to input type password. The app crash immediately with the following error on the Xcode:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DOMHTMLInputElement
>   __createInteractionAssistantIfNecessaryWithMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ....'

I cannot find more info about the __createInteractionAssistantIfNecessaryWithMode function; it seem like the private function of iPad OS.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="password" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add code?

Comment: @AlexH: I've added code it just simple HTML file loaded in a UIWebView

Comment: `UIWebView` is obsolete. It has been deprecated for years. You should use `WKWebView`.

Comment: And you should not be using any iOS 13 beta unless you mean iOS 13.2 beta.

Comment: @rmaddy: iOS 13.2 (17B5059f) problem have still happened.

Comment: Sounds like an issue in UIKit. Did you already report it to Apple via the Feedback Assistant app or http://feedbackassistant.apple.com?